# What's the difference between the minimum spanning tree algorithm for undirected vs directed graphs?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

Is the undirected graph MST algorithms (Prim's or Kruskal's) a general form of the directed MST algorithm (Edmond/Chiu)?  How come it's so difficult to find the MST source code for the directed case?  Can we use the undirected solution to obtain the MST in a directed graph?

This is related to the following:
[Why can't Prim's or Kruskal's algorithms be used on a directed graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649416/why-cant-prims-or-kruskals-algorithms-be-used-on-a-directed-graph)

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the question about finding a good library, since those sorts of questions aren't on-topic at Stack Overflow. However, the rest of your question is really interesting, so I'm going to try to answer it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The core of your question seems to be what makes finding an MST (technically called an *optimum branching* or *minimum-cost arborescence*) in a directed graph different and therefore harder than finding an MST in an undirected graph.

Both Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms work because of the *cut property*. If G = (V, E) is a graph, then for any cut (S, V - S) in G, if there is a least-cost edge {u, v} crossing that cut, that edge must belong to all MSTs of G. Unfortunately, this property isn't true in the directed case. Here's a counterexample:

```
      2
  A ----> B
  |      | ^
1 |  -99 | | 1
  |      v |
  +-----> C
```

Here, the minimum-cost arborescence rooted at A is this one:

```
      2
  A ----> B
          |
      -99 |
          v
          C
```

However, look at the cut ({A}, {B, C}) The least-cost edge crossing this cut is the edge (A, C), but that edge doesn't appear in any minimum-cost arborescence rooted at A.

Without the cut property, Prim's algorithm and Kruskal's algorithm both fail. Try running Prim's algorithm on the graph given here, starting with node A as your included node. You'll add in edge (A, C), then edge (C, B), giving a suboptimal arborescence. Now, try running Kruskal's algorithm here. You'll first add edge (B, C), then add edge (A, C). Unfortunately, this isn't actually an arborescence because it has no root node.

The standard algorithm for finding minimum-cost arborescences (Edmonds-Chu) is actually probably closer in spirit to [Boruvka's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm). Boruvka's algorithm works by simultaneously choosing, for each node, the least-cost edge connected to that node and adding it to the candidate MST. You then contract all CC's formed this way into single nodes and repeat this process until you have your tree.

In the undirected case, as long as the edge weights are distinct, this algorithm will never introduce a cycle (it's a good exercise to prove this), but this isn't the case in directed algorithms. The graph given above is a good example of this - if you try this, you pick (A, C) from A, (C, B) from C, and (B, C) from B, forming the cycle (B, C, B). The correction that the Edmonds-Chu algorithm uses works by contracting one of these cycles into a single node, then repeating this process in the reduced graph and "uncontracting" the cycles based on the result. In that sense it's similar to Boruvka's algorithm, though with appropriate modifications.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My experience is that, while it takes a while to grok, the primal-dual (linear programming) interpretation of these algorithms shines a lot of light on the connections between them.

Comment: Just love when I'm browsing here to answer some questions and find an answer so good it makes me learn a lot without even trying. Sad this kind of answer usually don't get many upvotes. Wish I could vote multiple times.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Among the many things I never learned in depth are how to approach algorithms from a primal-dual perspective. Do you have any good resources I could check out to learn more about them?

Comment: @templatetypedef [These lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-433-combinatorial-optimization-fall-2003/lecture-notes/l15.pdf) seem reasonable enough, though they do require some fluency with linear programming.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks, those look great. I do have a background in linear programming, fortunately (I took a class where we did some primal-dual algorithms). I can try to work through these and see if I can get a better handle on things.

Comment: @templatetypedef Interesting.  Thanks for that explanation, it adds some insights to the difference.  Is the undirected case more common, because i can't seem to find many implementation for the directed case and the one's i have found are usually incorrect.

Comment: @jortiz81 MSTs are taught a lot more than minimum-cost arborescences and from what I've seen they come up in practice a lot more. Whether that's because it's just more common or because min-cost arborescences aren't as well, though, is something I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 1):

I found some nice [slides](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/04GreedyAlgorithmsII.pdf) with a good, clear explanation of the difference and with clear figures and examples