# Kruskal's Algorith

Tags: c++, c++14, kruskals-algorithm

I am trying to implement kruskal's algo. togather with bfs and dfs. i wrote my code to print the adjancey list and to show the bfs and dfs and now i am facing problem with writing the code for kruskal's algorithm i kind of newbie in using maps and templates. i don't know how to pass the values in the kruskals algorithm and i m constantly getting errors.

here is the code that i have written.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<queue>
#include<list>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>

class Graph{

    private:
    map<T,list<pair<T,int>>>  l;

    void DFSHelper(T node,map<T,bool> &visited){

        cout<<node<<" -> ";
        visited[node]=true;

        for(auto neighbours:l[node]){

            if(!visited[neighbours.first]){

                DFSHelper(neighbours.first,visited);

            }
        }
    }

    public:

    void add(T A,T B,bool bi,int wi){

        l[A].push_back(make_pair(B,wi));

        if(bi == true){

            l[B].push_back(make_pair(A,wi));

        }
    }

    void print(){

        for(auto c:l){

            int c1 = c.first;

            list<pair<int,int>> n = c.second;

            cout<<c1<<" -> ";
            for(auto k:n){

                int dest = k.first;
                int dist = k.second;

                cout<<dest<<"("<<dist<<")  ";
            }
            cout<<endl;

        }     
    }

    void bfs(T src){

        map<T,bool> visited;
        queue<T> q;

        q.push(src);
        visited[src] = true;

        while(!q.empty()){

            T node = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout<<node<<" -> ";
            for(auto children:l[node]){

                if(!visited[children.first]){

                    visited[children.first]=true;

                    q.push(children.first);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    void dfs(T src){

        map<T,bool> visited;
        int component = 1;

        DFSHelper(src,visited);

    }

    void cmp(T src,T end){

        return src.second.second<end.second.second;

    }

    void kruskals(){



    }
};

int main(){

    Graph<int> g;

    g.add(1,2,true,20);
    g.add(1,3,true,30);
    g.add(2,4,true,50);
    g.add(3,4,true,10);
    g.add(4,5,true,60);
    g.add(5,1,false,35);

    g.print();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"BFS :- ";
    g.bfs(1);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"DFS :- ";
    g.dfs(1);
    g.kruskals();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your graph appears to be directed due to the uni-directional edge `5->1`. Kruskal's algorithm only works for undirected graphs. ([Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649416/why-cant-prims-or-kruskals-algorithms-be-used-on-a-directed-graph)?)

In Kruskal's algorithm you need the edges sorted in non-decreasing order of edge-weights. Hence you can either maintain an extra data structure alongwith the map `l` and insert to it in the `add()` function or create it in the `kruskals()` function itself.

Next you need a data structure to query if any two nodes of the graph belong to two different components or not. Here two nodes are said to be in the same component if you can reach one node to the other by only considering edges encountered till that particular iteration of the Kruskal's algorithm. A [Disjoint Set Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) can do that efficiently.

Here is an implementation, where I use the set `edge_weights` to store the edges sorted by weight:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<queue>
#include<list>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
#include <set> // Added
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class DisjointSetUnion {
    map<T, T> parent; 
    map<T, int> sz; // stores sizes of component
 public:
    void make_set(T v) {
        parent[v] = v;
    }
    T find_set(T x) {
        if(x != parent[x]) parent[x] = find_set(parent[x]);
        return parent[x];
    }
    void merge_sets(T x, T y) {
        int px = find_set(x), py = find_set(y);
        if(sz[px] > sz[py]) parent[py] = px;
        else parent[px] = py;
        if(sz[py] == sz[px]) sz[py]++;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Graph{
 private:
    map<T,list<pair<T,int>>>  l;
    set<pair<int, pair<T, T>>> edge_weights; // no parallel (or duplicate) edges exist
    void DFSHelper(T node,map<T,bool> &visited){

        cout<<node<<" -> ";
        visited[node]=true;

        for(auto neighbours:l[node]){

            if(!visited[neighbours.first]){

                DFSHelper(neighbours.first,visited);

            }
        }
    }

 public:

    void add(T A,T B,bool bi,int wi){

        l[A].push_back(make_pair(B,wi));

        if(bi == true){

            l[B].push_back(make_pair(A,wi));
            edge_weights.insert(make_pair(wi, make_pair(A, B))); // Added
        }
    }

    void print(){

        for(auto c:l){

            int c1 = c.first;

            list<pair<int,int>> n = c.second;

            cout<<c1<<" -> ";
            for(auto k:n){

                int dest = k.first;
                int dist = k.second;

                cout<<dest<<"("<<dist<<")  ";
            }
            cout<<endl;

        }     
    }

    void bfs(T src){

        map<T,bool> visited;
        queue<T> q;

        q.push(src);
        visited[src] = true;

        while(!q.empty()){

            T node = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout<<node<<" -> ";
            for(auto children:l[node]){

                if(!visited[children.first]){

                    visited[children.first]=true;

                    q.push(children.first);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    void dfs(T src){

        map<T,bool> visited;
        int component = 1;

        DFSHelper(src,visited);

    }

    void cmp(T src,T end){

        return src.second.second<end.second.second;

    }

    void kruskals(){
        DisjointSetUnion<int> dsu;
        // make singleton components of each node
        for(auto it: l) {
            T u = it.first;
            dsu.make_set(u);
        }
        // iterate over all edges in sorted order
        for(auto ed: edge_weights) {
            int w = ed.first;
            T u = ed.second.first, v = ed.second.second;
            // if they belong to different components then they are
            // part of the MST, otherwise they create a cycle
            if(dsu.find_set(u) != dsu.find_set(v)) {
                // this edge is part of the MST, do what you want to do with it!
                cout << "(" << u << "," << v << "," << w << "), ";
                // merge the two different components
                dsu.merge_sets(u, v);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(){

    Graph<int> g;

    g.add(1,2,true,20);
    g.add(1,3,true,30);
    g.add(2,4,true,50);
    g.add(3,4,true,10);
    g.add(4,5,true,60);
    // Removed unidirectional edge below
    // g.add(5,1,false,35); 

    g.print();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"BFS :- ";
    g.bfs(1);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"DFS :- ";
    g.dfs(1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Edges in MST (u,v,w): ";
    g.kruskals();
    cout << endl;

}
```